# Is there any way to make the formula bar in Excel 2008 on Mac OS X 10.6 dock or attach to the window instead of floating?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, worksheet-function, office-for-mac, microsoft-excel-2008

Is there any way to make the formula bar in Excel 2008 on Mac OS X 10.6 dock or attach to the window instead of floating?

So far everything I've read says no, but maybe you know the secret!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. I've checked out a lot of different forums and they've all said no.